# PHP: How to search for value or something similar on a mysql server?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am attempting to write a PHP script to search for a product on a MySQL server.
I am not sure of how to search for a value or something similar in the product name column. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Come on dude! At least give some detail or some of your previous tryings....

Comment: If you search the web for your question, you will find an answer.

Comment: When you say "sql server", do you mean MySQL? SQL Server is a totally different database product altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Write a PHP script that connects to your database. Then if everything worked out well you just have to execute (with PHP) the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_name LIKE 'name'
```

or if you want to just get the names that begin with a "A"

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_name LIKE 'A%'
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. I apologize for the lack of information I gave when posting this question. So I gather this query will select every variable from the column that is like the given query? All I need to do now is give a list of all the similar on a webpage so a user can view the results.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the LIKE operator and read the pattern matching page on Mysql site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for something that has a word in it then you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM web WHERE Description LIKE '%$each%' OR Title LIKE '%$each%'
```

That code when looking for "facebook"

would return any result that contains "facebook" anywhere within the database Description or Title sections that contain the word "facebook" at all